# Animation in RecyclerView works in debug mode, but not in release mode using Proguard

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, proguard

I'm trying to animate the items in a recyclerview, using the following code:

```
my_recyclerview.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(
            object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
                override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                    for (i in 0 until childCount) {
                        val view: View = getChildAt(i)

                        val translationValue = if (layoutManager?.width != null) -layoutManager!!.width.toFloat() else 0f

                        view.translationX = translationValue

                        val translationAnimator: Animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                            view, "translationX", translationValue, 0f
                        )
                        translationAnimator.duration = 300
                        translationAnimator.startDelay = i * 50.toLong()
                        translationAnimator.start()
                    }
                    return true
                }
            })
```

It works without any issue in the debug mode: items "slide in" one by one from the side.
However, when I generate the release apk, which uses proguard, no errors are thrown but the animation simply does not work.

Edited to clarify I did try with the release version without using Proguard (minifyEnabled false), and animation worked fine, so it has to be the obfuscation.

I have tried to include some "keep" rules in proguard for keeping ObjectAnimator, even the entire android.animation package, but either I'm not setting the rules correctly or I am missing something else.

For example, I tried:

```
-keep class android.animation.ObjectAnimator {*;}
```

as well as

```
-keep class android.animation.ObjectAnimator.** {*;}
```

and also this that I found Googling:

```
# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
```

**(Last Edit)** Also tried to include the most restrictive rules:

```
-keep class android.animation.ObjectAnimator { *; }
-keep class android.animation.ObjectAnimator {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
-keepclassmembers class android.animation.ObjectAnimator {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
-keep class android.widget.FrameLayout { *; }
-keep class android.widget.FrameLayout {
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}
-keepclassmembers class android.widget.FrameLayout {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

-keep class android.view.View { *; }
-keep class android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
-keepclassmembers class android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
```

At this point I tried so many alternatives I am completely lost.

Nothing worked. Any help or guidance would be really appreciated

Comment: What is the type of the `view` objects?

Comment: @StevenMeliopoulos view is a FrameLayout, and I'm using a FlexboxLayoutManager in my RecyclerView, in case it could be relevant

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think you're close with the last Proguard rule. This is a bit of a guess but could you try changing it to: -keepclassmembers class android.view.View{...} (leave the part in the braces unchanged). According to the Proguard docs, "extends" does not include the given class itself. https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage

Comment: If the above doesn't work I would try generalizing the rule more until it works and then restricting it again step by step to see at which part it breaks.

Comment: @StevenMeliopoulos tried and still not working. What would be the more restrictive rule for this case? I honestly don't even know what else to try. Last thing I tried was -keep class android.widget.FrameLayout { *; } and even -keep class android.view.View { *; }. Also with void set*(***);
    *** get*();